# C-Code to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I was trying to convert C code to MIPS assembly. There are these two following C code snippets. The problem is that my solution differs from the standard solution. Also, I don't understand the standard solution. I hoped, someone could explain me the two following mips assembly code snippets.

First of all some additional information for the task. Only the following MIPS instructions are allowed: **lw, add, beq, bne and j**.

The register:

**$s3** contains **i**

**$s4** contains **j**

**$s5** contains **k**

**A** is an array of **32-Bit-Integer** and the initial address of **A** is in **$s6**

 **$t0** and **$t1** can be used for storing temporary variables

The first one is a simple do-while loop:

```
do {
    i = i + j;
} while(A[i] == k);
```

MIPS Assembly

```
loop: add $s3, $s3, $s4   // this is i = i+j
      add $t1, $s3, $s3  // from now on
      add $t1, $t1, $t1  // I cant follow anymore
      add $t1, $t1, $s6  // What happens in these three lines?
      lw  $t0, 0($t1)    // 0($t1) is new for me. What does this zero do?
      beq $t0, $s5, loop
```

Now the second C code:

```
if ( i == j )
    i = i + A[k];
else if( i == k )
    i = i + A[j];
else
   i = i + k;
```

Here is the MIPS assembly code:

```
       bne $s3, $s4, Else1  // this line is if(i==j)
       add $t1, $s5, $s5   // from here on
       add $t1, $t1, $t1   // till
       add $t1, $t1, $s6  // 
       lw  $t0, 0($t1)    //
       add $s3, $s3, $t0  // here I don't understand
       j done
ELSE1: bne $s3, $s5, Else2  // this line is if(i==k)
       add $t1, $s4, $s4   // The same game as above
       add $t1, $t1, $t1
       add $t1, $t1, $s6
       lw  $t0, 0($t1)
       add $s3, $s3, $t0  // till here
       j done
ELSE2: add $s3, $s4, $s5
```

Could anyone explain me what really goes on? That would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

O.k. the most interesting and not-understandable piece of code is the following:add $t1,

```
add $t1, $s5, $s5
add $t1, $t1, $t1
add $t1, $t1, $s6
```

this code multiplies $s5 by four, and stores it in $t1, then adds to $t1 $s6. That is equivalent to:

```
$t1 = A[k]
```

after you understand this, the code looks much clearer.

about the `lw  $t0, 0($t1)`:

you can use an offset point in the address. Here the offset is 0.

Answer (score 1):

`lw` is load.  The mode here is indirect addressing, the most common is:

```
lw $t2, ($t0)
```

But you can also include a byte offset,

```
lw $t2, 4($t0)   # load word at RAM address ($t0 + 4) into register $t2
```

The compiler is just putting the 0 placeholder in the non-offset version.

So, to load `A[i]` you need to do two things.  Take the base address of `A[]` and then add `i` times the `sizeof(A[0])`.  I am guessing that the values in `A` are 32 bit.

```
add $t1, $s3, $s3
```

`$t1 = j + j` or `2 * j`

```
add $t1, $t1, $t1
```

`$t1 = $t1 + $t1` or `j +j +j +j` or `4 * j`

So why did it do it this way?  Well, doing a straight multiply is slow in terms of clock cycles.  The next choice would be a shift operation, but in this case, the compiler designers decided that two adds beat a shift.

```
add $t1, $t1, $s6
```

I would guess that `$s6` is the base address of `A[]`.  So ultimately '$t1 = A[] + 4 * j`

Comment: Ok. Now everything seems to be little bit clearer. But I have question to the offset. **lw $t2, 0($t0)** is equivalent to load the address at **($t0 + 0)**. Could I omit the "0" in the above case and just make **lw $t2, ($t0)**?

Comment: Yes, in the MIPS assembler pages I found, `lw $t2, ($t0)` is a valid form.

Comment: Hi woolster, I question came up. The designer decided to use two addition instead of multiplication, perhaps because performance issues as you said. But why does the designer use a multiplication with 4 anyway? Of course, the numbers in the the array are 32 bit integers. So, they are 4 byte large, but we don't know how large the variables i, j and k are. Maybe each of them is 4 byte large. Then we wouldn't need to multiply the A[] with 4 to get the next value? I think the designer assumes the variables are 1 byte large. Can that be true?

Comment: @user2965601 The variables are being held in registers. The MIPS registers are all 4 bytes large. If the values in those registers are less than 256, it doesn't change the fact that the registers can contain up to 4 bytes. In addition, the times 4 still needs to be done, so that the code writes to the array in the correct slot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a answer.The loop, a is array of elements have basic address :0x0FE3B128.
Thanks all so much.. 
and this is my homework, I don't sure that it is correct.

```html
    for(i=1; i!=20;i+=3){
        a[i]= a[5]+1;
        }
lui    $s0, 0x0FE3
ori    $s0, $0, B128
lw     $t1, 20($s0)
addi   $s1, $0, 1
addi   $s2, $0, 20
LOOP     beq $s1, $s2, DONE
         add $t1, $t1, $s1
         sll $t1, $t1, 2
         sw   $t2, 0($t1)
         addi  $s1, $0, 3
          j LOOP
DONE
```